# React prevent body from scrolling if popup is open

Tags: reactjs

React prevent body from scrolling if popup is open.
How can i disable the background body from scrolling when the pop up div is open.

```
function FilterButton() {
let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);


return (
    <div className='filter-button'>
        <div className="name-filter" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
            <p>Filter</p>
            <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
        {
            isOpen ? <div className="background-blur">
                <div className="filter-popup">
                    <p className='filter-by-name'>Filter By Type</p>
                    <hr />
                    <div className="filter-types">
                        <div className="filter">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="apply-cancel">
                        <button className="apply">Apply</button>
                        <button className="cancel" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                : null
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock) library to help you with that.
Here is how it could work on your component. I haven't tested it tho.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  disableBodyScroll, 
  enableBodyScroll, 
  clearAllBodyScrollLocks 
} from 'body-scroll-lock';

function FilterButton() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const popupRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      popupRef.current && disableBodyScroll(popupRef.current)
    } else {
      popupRef.current && enableBodyScroll(popupRef.current)
    }
  }, [isOpen])

  return (
    <div className="filter-button">
      <div className="name-filter" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
        <p>Filter</p>
        <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>
      </div>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div className="background-blur">
          <div className="filter-popup" ref={popupRef}>
            <p className="filter-by-name">Filter By Type</p>
            <hr />
            <div className="filter-types">
              <div className="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="apply-cancel">
              <button className="apply">Apply</button>
              <button className="cancel" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's working. Please have a look at the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-with-body-scroll-lock-c4lnu) for a demo. I think `popupRef.current &&` is not needed. Also adding the option `reserveScrollBarGap: true` to `disableBodyScroll` could be added to reduce content jumps because of the scrollbar.